# How to solve the complex equation? $(x+2yi)^2 = xi.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How to solve the following complex equation with in less than 60 seconds?

$$(x+2yi)^2 = xi.$$

I know how to solve, we have to solve power first then real part equal to real part and imaginary to imaginary.

Is there any simplest method than above to solve this one?

Comment: I don't think the method you described should take very long.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow exactly as you outlined using some simple tricks:

- The square of a complex number is complex
- $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$

Note that when you square $x + 2yi$ the only real terms will be $x^2$ and $(2yi)^2$ so add those and set them equal to zero off the bat and get a relation between $x,y$
$$
x^2 - 4y^2 = 0 \implies x = \pm 2y
$$
Then follow up with the complex equation
$$
4xyi = xi \implies y = 1/4 \implies x = \pm 1/2 
$$

Now I was able to do this while watching futurama and sleep deprived in about 100 seconds. I hope this provides at least some help!

Comment: 100 seconds. In the exactly same way i have done this question. By the way thanks DanZimm.

Comment: @zonnie how long did it take you?

Comment: You missed a solution.

Comment: approximately same time DanZimm.

Comment: @Michael hrm let me guess, $x=y=0$?

Comment: @zonnie well I think the only way to optimize time spent on problems like this are by doing many examples over and over and noticing small tricks and symmetries in certain problems.

Comment: Yeah thanks DanZimm. Well what is meant by x = y = 0?

Comment: @zonnie a) if this answer answered your question then mark it as so as to close the question. b) $x=y=0$ is also a solution to this equation.

Comment: How is (b) the solution?

Comment: @zonnie plug in $x = 0, y = 0$ then you get that $(0 + 0)^2 = 0$ which is true.